# Question about adding probability

Tags: probability

Let's say we have an algorithm that goes trough 6 steps one by one. To reach the next step you need to pass trough the previous step. Each step has a % chance for you to be stopped. So if you are stopped you can't reach the final step. If I have the chances of being stopped for each step, how do I add them up so I can find the chance to be stopped on the final step? For instance if I have:
10% to pass the first step
30% chance to pass the second step
50% chance to pass the third step

What's the total chance of passing the third step? Is it just combining all $3$ probabilities and dividing by $3$? Or is it more complex?

Comment: You have three events that are independent so passing all three steps is just product of the probabilities of each, for your example P = 0.1*0.3*0.5

Answer (score 0):

You multiply them. The events are independent, so that's how you get the chance of all of them happening.
$$0.1 \cdot 0.3 \cdot 0.5 = 0.015 = 1.5\%$$